# How can I iterate through the elements of a QStack object?

Tags: c++, qt

I've started using Qt's classes recently in my university, and got kinda impressed with its efficiency. Going through the documentation, I found some information about [QStack](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstack.html) and [QQueue](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqueue.html), both classes useful for projects I'm developing.

However, I've been facing quite a puzzle: **how can I iterate through all elements of a QStack object?**

For example, let's say I want to iterate through the elements of the `stack` object in the example below ([extracted from Qt's documentation about QStack](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstack.html)):

```
QStack<int> stack;
stack.push(1);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(3);
while (!stack.isEmpty())
    cout << stack.pop() << endl;
```

I managed to do so by removing each element of the stack, one by one, and saving them on a temp list, but this seems like a terrible way to solve this problem. What else could I do?

Comment: If you need to iterate content, `std::vector` (or `QVector` or even `QList`) might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QStack inherits from QVector so you *can* (but most likely *shouldn't*) iterate same way as you do with QVector.

```
QStack <int> stack;
stack.push(1);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(3);

for (int i : stack)
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

However, there is a very good chance that you should **NOT** be using stack if you need to iterate. Just use the actual QVector.

The point of using a Stack is to "enforce" LIFO (Last In First Out) ordering on items. If you are iterating over them in any particular order you are breaking the order enforced by Stack and so (very likely) should NOT be using a stack in the first place.

P.S. This was focused on QStack, but the same reasoning applies to QQueue as well. Differences are that Queue enforces FIFO (First In First Out) ordering and in QT QQueue inherits from QList, so replace it with QList not QVector.

Comment: I see. But since I would only use QVector only to *read* each element without removing nor changing it, would it really be troublesome? When editing, adding or removing elements, my idea is to still work with the LIFO ordering concept.

Comment: hmm, not sure what you mean by "troublesome"?
When adding/removing/accessing last element you can use QVector's push_back(), pop_back() and back()(or last()) members instead of QStack's push(), pop() and top().

Comment: I don't see a reason why you shouldn't leverage the `QVector` properties of `QStack`. [They are explicitly documented as part of the API](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstack.html#public-functions). Keep in mind, though, that many C++ programmers might not be familiar with the characteristics of the Qt containers. Instead they might expect `QStack` to behave like a pure stack (e.g. like `std::stack`). That's why I usually prefer the standard library containers.

Answer (score 0):

[The Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#the-container-classes) says about `QStack`:

> This is a convenience subclass of QVector that provides "last in, first out" (LIFO) semantics. It adds the following functions to those already present in QVector: push(), pop(), and top().

As [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10865566/david) pointed out you can iterate over the entries in a `QStack` the same way you iterate over a `QVector`:

```
QStack <int> stack;
stack.push(1);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(3);

for (int i : stack)
{
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

BTW: The [standard library's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) comes with a similar page describing the properties of it's containers - these pages are generally very helpful when deciding which container to use.